# Customizing the dialog image and banner image in WIX installer

Tags: wix, installation, themes

I had Created **wix installer** project to my C# windows forms application.

I am  new in using wix Toolset. I am wondering if there is anything like theme file, from which I can change the dialog image and banner image, as I need to distribute this installer for different customers, and I should set the look and feel of their logo. I want them to feel like this installer is customized specially for them.

I mean, I don't want to change the dialog image and the banner image each time from inside .wxs file. I imagine that there may be something like a **.theme** file from which I can set the images every time I need to change it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to change the image and the banner you should use:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="$(var.ResourcesDir)bannrbmp.bmp" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="$(var.ResourcesDir)BackgroundImage.bmp" />
```

Different files for different customers.

There is no theme file you can change every time you need to change.

Comment: when i am using $(var.ResourcesDir) it gives me an error when trying to build wix installer project , The error is Error 1 Undefined preprocessor variable '$(var.ResourcesDir)'. Originally  i was setting them like that <WixVariable Id="WixUIDialogBmp" Value="WixUIDialog.bmp" />

Comment: You should set a path to bpm files. $(var.ResourcesDir) is set in the include file like this <?define ResourcesDir = $(sys.CURRENTDIR)..\..\Resources\?> You can set as C:\resources\bannrbmp.bmp. this will work to but more elegant way to do is as I described above.

Comment: aha, so u mean i should set the definition of [ResourcesDir] in an include file in order to be able to use it in .wxs file as u described in the solution above , aren't you ?

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to do it. Clean code is important thing 

Comment: I really appreciate your help , Thanks very much. Just one more question , is there is anything i can do to set , Dialog image,Banner image and Application name ,Dynamically into the installer after it has been build . I know it may be a stupid question , but i am asking cause i may deliver this .msi file into some IT people who would be responsible about changing this stuff.

Comment: Yes, try to use orca or insted it!.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the image size & position inside WixVariable or somewhere outside?

Comment: As you can see above there is a capability to use a variable for the location of the logo - there is no reason that I can think of not to have an environment variable used to point to a different location per customer pointing to a directory containing that customers logo, banner, etc. This should give you what you need. `Value="$(env.CUSTOMERIMAGES)\...` looks to be the syntax for accessing something like this.